# Passing an object C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, object, treeview, parameter-passing

I am new to c# and am having issues with the syntax and passing an object.  I am building a form with a treeview of stores and a list view of customers for each store.  When I click a button on the form, 'OnStoreAdd' is called and creates the store object.  How do I pass that object to 'AddStoreNode(object?tag?)'?

```
namespace CustomerInfoObjects
{
    public class Store
    {
        private List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();

        public List<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return _customers; }
            set { _customers = value; }
        }

        private string _name = string.Empty;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
}

namespace DomainObjects
{
    public class CustomerList : List<Customer> { }
    public class StoreToCustomerListDictionary : Dictionary<Store, CustomerList> { }
    public class CustomerInfoDocument
    {
        private StoreToCustomerListDictionary _storeToCustomerList = new StoreToCustomerListDictionary();
        public StoreToCustomerListDictionary StoreToCustomerList
        {
            get { return _storeToCustomerList; }
            set { _storeToCustomerList = value; }
        }
    }
}

namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public static class CustomerMgr
    {
        private static CustomerInfoDocument _document = new CustomerInfoDocument();

        public static bool AddStore(string storeName)
        {
            Store store = new Store();
            store.Name = storeName;
            _document.StoreToCustomerList.Add(store, null);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

namespace UILayer
{
    public partial class StoreTreeControl : UserControl
    {
        public StoreTreeControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddStoreNode(Store object? )    //What type of argument?
        {
            TreeNode node = _tvwStores.Nodes.Add(store.Name);
            node.Tag = store;
            _tvwStores.SelectedNode = node;
        }

        private void OnStoreAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            StorePropertiesForm f = new StorePropertiesForm();
            if (f.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)  
                return;                             

            if (!CustomerMgr.AddStore(f.StoreName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Store name should no be blank");
                return;
            }

            AddStoreNode(?);  //What argument would I use here?
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass the new store object into the AddStoreNode method.  The tag in AddStoreNode method is so that my listview can access treeview nodes.  Do I need another tag in the StoreAdd method to use?

Any information that could point me in the right great direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Why would you have a class store that has a property Customers and a Dictionary( Store, Customers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the business layer `AddStore` to return the store object added to the internal list

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public static class CustomerMgr
    {
        private static CustomerInfoDocument _document = new CustomerInfoDocument();

        public static Store AddStore(string storeName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(storeName))
                return null;

            Store store = new Store();
            store.Name = storeName;
            _document.StoreToCustomerList.Add(store, null);
            return store;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the user interface you could get back the same instance

```
private void OnStoreAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    StorePropertiesForm f = new StorePropertiesForm();
    if (f.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)  
        return;                             

    Store currentStore = CustomerMgr.AddStore(f.StoreName);
    if (currentStore == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Store name should no be blank");
        return;
    }

    AddStoreNode(currentStore);  
}
public void AddStoreNode(Store aStoreToAdd)    
{
    TreeNode node = _tvwStores.Nodes.Add(aStoreToAdd.Name);
    node.Tag = aStoreToAdd;
    _tvwStores.SelectedNode = node;
}
```